# ASSERT like pattern in SQLite statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm looking for a python assert-like pattern for a pure SQL statement in SQLite3.
In python I could write code

```
assert len(my_var)==1, "Unexpected length, raise an error"
```

Is there a pattern I can use to achieve the same in an SQLite3 call that would be executed from the command-line in the form:

```
sqlite3 my_database.db < script.sql > output.tsv
```

The structure of the problem is this. Given a table with columns (col_A, col_B, col_C), column C is a hash of A and B, such that unique pairs of A and B are expected to produce a unique value for C, and duplicate pairs of A and B produce the same value for C. I'm interested in getting

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY A, B;
```

However, there exists the slim possibility of my hashing algorithm producing a different value for identical A,B pairs (don't ask about the hashing algorithm, this is a frictionless metaphor operating in a vacuum). In the SELECT above, for SQLite, I believe the behavior would be to silently get the first value for C and discard the rest. I could use GROUP_CONCAT and save all the values, I don't want my hash value to possibly become a separated string. I could just GROUP BY A, B, C, but later steps depend on AB pairs being unique. Really, the behavior I'd like to see is that the query blows up and complains.

Is there a way of *asserting* that GROUP BY A, B didn't discard any values for C? Or that LENGTH(GROUP BY A, B) == LENGTH(GROUP BY A, B, C)

Comment: If later steps depend on `A, B` being unique, would it be enough to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `A, B` here already, preventing duplicate A, B values altogether, and ignoring the C column completely?

Comment: [mcve] would help.

Comment: Ah, that's it @WanderNauta. In the background I'm putting these results into a TEMP TABLE so I can index and do a big JOIN without making my head explode. I'll just GROUP BY A,B,C and UNIQUE index on A,B. If you want the imaginary internet points, frame that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Otherwise, I'll post it myself so I can mark the question answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, especially...

> later steps depend on A, B pairs being unique

...one approach that comes close is to already enforce at this stage that the pairs must be unique:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    A,
    B, 
    C,
    UNIQUE (A, B)
);
```

That way, there are never duplicate pairs of (A, B) -- SQLite won't let you insert them -- and because there cannot be duplicates, there can never be a case where their C columns disagree.

Comment: Note that `UNIQUE` constraints [allow multiple `NULL` values](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q26), so you may want to declare these columns as `NOT NULL` if this is undesired behavior.